# Executing python file through JSP

Tags: python, jsp

I am creating a simple web page which reads from the database and display on the browser.
I have a python script which reads from a file and updates the database for the changes made in the file.
I want to add a button in my webpage which executes this python file and display the updated information on the webpage.

Is there a way to link the execution of the python file to the button present on the webpage.

Any suggestions or reference is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDITs:

I went through a couple of reference but those were not of much help.
I am not using jython or any other application that supports both java and python.
Is there a way to do it without using any other application.

Comment: Have you resolved this query? I have same requirement and I am stuck with it, Could you give me some reference for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is the same way you would do it normally in Java.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8